# Using custom tokenizer in R converting text to vector?

Tags: python, r, vector, machine-learning, data-science

Is there any way in R so that I can convert text to vector using my own tokenizer?
`vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=getTokens)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)`
Above code is written in python and getTokens is my custom tokenizer is there anyway so that I can do the same thing in R.
There are some Things I want to mention like there is a library in R `library(text2vec)` also but I am not getting How to apply my custom Tokenizer in R
Tokens=words

Answer (score 2):

"Tokenization is the process of splitting a text into tokens". I assume that with tokens you refer to words. This can be done in R using e.g. strsplit on a low level. For example:

```
> example <- "This is an example. This is an example"
> unlist(strsplit(example, split = " "))
[1] "This"     "is"       "an"       "example." "This"     "is"       "an"       "example"
```

As you can see the string is automatically transformed into a vector with several character strings. Now splitting by a simple space doesn't handle special cases well. So using a regex for one or more non-alphanumeric character should be considered better:

```
> unlist(strsplit(example, split = "[^[:alnum:]]+"))
[1] "This"    "is"      "an"      "example" "This"    "is"      "an"      "example"
```

If you want to preserve the punctuation you can use `"\\s+"` aka whitespace instead alnum. We can wrap this into a function:

```
> tokenize <- function(x){
+   unlist(strsplit(example, split = "\\s+"))
+ }
> tokenize(example)
 [1] "This"      "is"        "an"        "example."  "This"      "is"        "an"        "example"
```

If you want to have tokens different from word (e.g. sentence or character). You could use the tokenizer from quanteda which can handle special cases where e.g. the period does not indicate a new sentence:

```
> example <- "This is an example. This is an example Dr. Knowitall"
> quanteda::tokens(example, what = "sentence")
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "This is an example."              "This is an example Dr. Knowitall"
```

There are several other packages that come with their own tokenizers. The package tokenizers, for example, provides just that.

Comment: basically I want to use this thing in URl detection for that I have to create Urls in vector form and predict the score is there any way I can do so or Can u please create the function same in R.It will be a great help.@jonGrub

Comment: Please add this to your question then and give an example of a few URLs that you want tokenized. As you can see it depends mostly on what you write into the split option. If URLs are seperated by comma, for example, you can put this into the function.

Comment: Please go through the github link:https://github.com/keshavm021/Using-Machine-Learning-in-R-Detecting-Malicious-Urls/blob/master/keshav.R you will understand what is happening and it will be  great help.@jongrub

Comment: I don't think that helps much. The script is apparently pointing to a selection of URLs in `all_url='/home/mifi/Desktop/R_project_detecting _malicious_url/original_dataset/data.csv'`. As I can not look into this file I don't think I can help you. Just provide an example of how the URLs sit in this file. If each is in a "cell" than read.csv should be able to seperate them from each other anyway. By the way, the standard option in R is to convert strings to factors when reading in csv files. You can turn that off with read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)...

Comment: diaryofagameaddict.com,bad This is how the url looks like.

Comment: And I have uploaded the dataset file on the above GitHub link.@jonGrub

Comment: After looking at the file I'm even more confused what your problem is. `all_url_csv <- read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` gives me a perfectly good data.frame with one column of URLs and one with good/bad. I don't see a need for any sort of tokenizer here.